# JAXB IDREF and ID usage?

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb

I'm looking to write an XSD which will be used to generate some Java classes via JAXB. I'd like the resulting XML to look like this:

```
<Appointment>
    <Patient ref="12345">Bob Smith</Patient>
    <Type>Some Appointment Type</Type>
    <Date>2010-02-17</Date>
    ....
</Appointment>
```

So, given this schema I'm wanting it to generate a class where I can just do something like this:

```
Patient p = loadPatientFromDB();
Appointment a = new Appointment();
a.setPatient(p);
a.setType("Some Appointment Type");
```

I think what I am looking to do involves having an element which has an IDREF as an attribute and then a string as the contents of the element.

Can someone give me a hand with some of the XSD?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

This question could likely also be asked in the following manner.

Can a simpleType have an attribute, or must it be a complexType.

So, can you have

> ```
>   <element id="foo">bar</element>
> ```

or must you have

> ```
>   <element id="foo"><name>bar</name></element>
> ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will answer your second question, since it's very clearly asked. No, a simple type cannot have an attribute. What you are looking for is a complex type with simple content:

```
<xs:complexType name="Person">
    <xs:simpleContent>
        <xs:extension base="xs:string">
           <xs:attribute name="ref" type="xs:IDREF" use="required"/>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

**Edit:** You can now use this type as you intended, assign it to an element called "person" and you can have `<person id="foo">A Name</person>`.

As for the first question: you still have a bit of extra work if you actually want the IDs resolved. For example, [see here](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/2005/08/15/pluggable-ididref-handling-jaxb-20).